# What happens to the staging area (and staged file) when commit is executed (other than the fact that the file gets commited to the repository)?

Tags: git

I am trying to visualize what happens when a staged file is committed.

Once commit is executed, I know that the file gets committed to the repository. However, does the file also remain in the stage (index) or does it get deleted from the stage (index)? What happens to the staging area (and staged file) when commit is executed?

Comment: @Youssef13: although that's a reasonable experiment, it's hard to see what is actually *in* the index: `git status` doesn't show you what is there, it just shows you the result of *comparing* what's there to what's elsewhere. If you know about `git ls-files --stage`, you can use that to see what's in the index, but not all tutorials tell you about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stage (index) is

- a copy of the commit referenced by `HEAD`
- plus any additional changes due to "staged files".

When you make a commit, the content of the index becomes the content of the new commit and `HEAD` is changed to reference the new commit. At this point, the index becomes a copy of the commit referenced by `HEAD` (by definition), but without any additional changes.

So, no, the file is not deleted from the index.